# OpenGl - Colour between matrix()

Tags: opengl

Hello
how i can apply in OpenGL between various Gl.glPushMatrix(); different colours in text.

I have one text with yellow colour and automatically when i start run the game the text stay with other colour.

Comment: How are you drawing the text?

Answer (score 1):

OpenGL is a state machine, so that anything you set will automatically be applied to further drawing operation.

If you change the text color for example, all text will be drawn with the new text color unless you change it back to what it was before.

[OpenGL does not support drawing text natively, so you're probably using a library to do so. That's typically how most OpenGL libraries work though]